# PHP Contact form connects but does not submit

Tags: php, forms

Hi there guys this is my PHP for a contact form. It connect succesfully as I ran some tests at various points to see if it worked however it does not seem to submit to the database. Can anyone help me?

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME', 'x');
define('DB_USER', 'x');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'x');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

$value = $_POST['UserName'];
$value1 = $_POST['UserEmail'];
$value2 = $_POST['UserMessage'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO ContactUs (UserName, UserEmail, UserMessage) VALUES ('$value', '$value1', '$value2')";


if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_close();
```

I have also attached blow the actual snippet of code for the contact form (its in a modal box):

```
<div class = "modal fade" id = "contact" role="dialog">
<div class = "modal-dialog">
<div class = "modal-content">
<div class = "modal-header">
<h4>Contact form</h4>
</div>
<div class = "modal-body">
<p>HELLO HELLO HELLO HELLO</p>
</div>
   <div class="form-group">
<form action="ContactUs.php" method="post">

 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="UserEmail">Email address</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="UserEmail" name="UserEmail" placeholder="What is your E-Mail">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="UserName">Name</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="UserName" name="UserName" placeholder="What is your name?">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="UserMessage">Message</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="UserMessage" name="UserMessage" placeholder="What would you like to say?">
 </div>
 <input type="Submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>

</form>
</div>

<div class = "modal-footer">
<a class = "btn btn-default" data-dismiss = "modal">Close</a>
<a class = "btn btn-primary" data-dismiss = "modal">Close</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Seing how this is a contact form I simply want the information to be sent to my email, if anyone could tell me whether this is suitable that would be great [if its not how to adjust it to make it so]. I used a video tutorial [link below] but he only mentioned how to store into the database.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wp6Ngpk5XiY

Comment: You have a typo: `if (!link)` ? - Other than that typo and not using MySQLi instead of the deprecated MySQL there is nothing syntactically wrong with your script.

Comment: Also, I'd strongly recommend that you stop using mysql and take a look at either mysqli or PDO, mysql is **deprecated**

Comment: are you getting any errors ? or any output ?

Comment: Give your submit a name,and remove that orphan button tag which somehow got lost in there.Then check with isset($_POST[submit_name])

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL injection as well. The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Use MySQLi instead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a typo when examining `if (!link)`, but, additionally, you should be using the newer, safer `MySQLi` functionality. Try this:

```
<?php
define('DB_NAME', 'x');
define('DB_USER', 'x');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'x');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno)
{
    die("Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

$userName = $_POST['UserName'];
$userEmail = $_POST['UserEmail'];
$userMessage = $_POST['UserMessage'];

if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO ContactUs (UserName, UserEmail, UserMessage) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")))
{
    die("Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error);
}

$stmt->bind_param("sss", $userName, $userEmail, $userMessage);
if (!$stmt->execute())
{
    die("INSERT failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error);
}

$mysqli->close();
```

This uses [Prepared Statements](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), which, for all intents and purposes, replace the `?` marks in the prepared statement definition with the escaped values of variables you bind to the statement. This helps to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: I have added this in and added the VALUES that were ?, ?, ? as what you can see below. 

Now when i try to go directly to the www.gemcode.co.uk/ContactUs.php it creates an empty field in the database but when i try to input something into the contact form itself it does not work.

if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO ContactUs (UserName, UserEmail, UserMessage) VALUES ('$UserName', '$UserEmail', '$UserMessage')")))

Comment: No no, you don't replace the `?` marks with anything. This code should be correct as it is. Try it without changing anything.

Comment: Also, if it doesn't work, try adding `var_dump($_POST['UserName'], $_POST['UserEmail'], $_POST['UserMessage']);` before the query to see what data is being posted to your `ContactUs.php`.